# Kubernetes POD networks metrics not showing in monitoring (prometheus / grafana / lens)

Tags: kubernetes, networking, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, grafana

I have a Kubernetes cluster set up in Google's GKE.
Prometheus/Grafana is installed with helm:

https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack

Monitoring works nicely out of the box. Nonetheless there are some pods in a specific namespace (let's call it namespace-X) which don't show Network metrics (they show CPU and Memory metrics, but no network). Only one Pod shows network metrics in namespace-X.
Throughout the other namespaces network metrics are shown.

I am checking for the network metrics both on Grafana's pre-built dashboards and on Lens.

```
Kubernetes Version: v1.22.6-gke.300
Grafana: v.8.4.5
Prometheus: quay.io/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator:v0.55.0
```

Is there some additional scraping configurations I need to set up on prometheus or on the deployments?

Comment: You could have a look at the local node collectors endpoint if they don't show up there either. If they don't the next step would be looking at the source. Should be cAdvisor I think.
You could also query the summay api on the Kubelet to see if the data is present there.